# Unity drag&drop, struggle with index problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing drag and drop function. in unity 2d

**Three options, and one blank**

I put three options and it named "option1" , "option2", "option3"

**This scene blank is supposed to match option3

Next scene blank is supposed to match option1

Last scene blank is supposed to match option2**

This is what i want. But it says

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
streetlight_dragdrop.Start () (at

(I used this codes another func that "3 options and 3 blanks" it worked okay. 
BUT it is not working this situation...)

```
public GameObject[] options; //drag options objects
public GameObject[] blankoptions; //blank
Vector3[] optionsStartPos;
Vector3[] blankoptionsStartPos;




void Start()
{

    optionsStartPos = new Vector3[options.Length];
    blankoptionsStartPos = new Vector3[blankoptions.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
    {
        optionsStartPos[i] = options[i].transform.position;
        blankoptionsStartPos[i] = blankoptions[i].transform.position;
    }
}


public void dragOptions(GameObject option)
{
    option.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
}


public void dropOptions(GameObject option)
{

    int index = System.Array.IndexOf(options, option);
    float dist = Vector3.Distance(option.transform.position, blankoptions[index].transform.position);
    if (dist < 80) //correct
    {
        option.transform.position = blankoptions[index].transform.position;

        if (gameObject.name == "option3")
        {
            //after 2sec, scene change func
            Invoke("street_5", 2);
        }

    }

    //incorrect
    else
    {
        Handheld.Vibrate();
        option.transform.position = optionsStartPos[index];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Hopefully I understand this correctly - as you didn't post the whole error message) **In this loop, you are looping from 0 to options.Length, but what if blankoptions.Length is less? or vice versa? This will likely cause a " Index was outside the bounds" error.**

```
for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
{
    optionsStartPos[i] = options[i].transform.position;
    blankoptionsStartPos[i] = blankoptions[i].transform.position;
}
```

For example:

```
optionsStartPos = new Vector3[10];
blankoptionsStartPos = new Vector3[1000];
for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
{
    optionsStartPos[i] = options[i].transform.position;
    blankoptionsStartPos[i] = blankoptions[i].transform.position;
}
```

would cause this error.